# Caml query returns wrong rows

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I've an issue with a caml query - to select a sharepoint item where the field "Title" is of a specific value...

```
  Dim camlQuery As New CamlQuery()
  camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Query><where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" & orderno & "</value></Contains></where></Query>"
```

Problem is this returns all the items in the list.
Orderno will be a guid, so it is unique.
I've read a few questions on here that have had a few suggestions but nothing has worked.

I've tried replacing

```
  <eq>
```

with

```
  <contains>
```

But that's no use.
The start of the query used to read

```
  <View><Query>
```

And I've changed it but that's had no effect either.
As far as I can see the query looks OK - not sure why this is going wrong.

Edit:
Also, this is using microsoft.sharepoint.client so .items() isn't available on the list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CAML in your question has syntax problems because CAML is case sensitive.

`<where>` should be `<Where>`, `</where>` should be `</Where>`, and `</value>` should be `</Value>`. (Similary, `<eq>` should be `<Eq>` and `<contains>` should be `<Contains>`.)

You should wrap the entire CAML query in `<View></View>` tags when setting it as the value for the `.ViewXml` property. If you want to add a `<RowLimit>` element, it would come after the closing `</Query>` tag but before the closing `</View>` tag.

Comment: Yep - that sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Caml Query Builder in this case. it will help you to get expected result and one more important point here is you need to use "View" tag in Client Side Object model when you try to fetch List Items.

It might help you :)

Comment: that looks like it could be useful - any idea how you specify proxy creds when connecting - my security setup at work is stupid and doesnt allo wanything

Comment: it will take your system credential when using sharepoint on-prem environment if you are using sharepoint online then download this https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/caml-designer-for-sharepoint-2013-released/

Comment: you can search caml-designer-for-sharepoint-2013-released and you will get lots of tool available 
and try with that.

take a chance and let me know if you are not able to do that i will provide you a sample query :)

Comment: could you give me a sample? Keep getting 407 with the u2u tool - same with the one from http://www.camldesigner.com/index.php/2016/01/12/caml-designer-2013/

Comment: faisl as well - 407 for some reason